# Why do I have to use %(objecttype) and %(rest) to filter blobs

Tags: git

I am using git 2.3.0, and trying to find all blob ids.

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype)' | grep blob | wc -l
0
$ git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(rest)' | grep blob | wc -l
0
$ git rev-list --objects --all | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(rest)'  | grep blob | wc -l
138189
```

Why is only the last output nonzero?

(And if you do happen to know of a better way of obtaining all blob ids, let me know.)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> If `--batch` or `--batch-check` is given, `cat-file` will read
>   objects from stdin, one per line, and print information about
>   them. By default, the whole line is considered as an object, as
>   if it were fed to **git-rev-parse**(1).

Let's take a look at some sample `git rev-list --objects --all` output:

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all | head -3 | vis -l
d1eae6908f5327c4c1a607cab1c449e71a08c7d7\$
f557ce992dfd61ee7e660eeabb638b99e19bd603\$
ea4daf67a352fa86362e19bb02fd0501a74d26fa\$
```

(these look pretty good, they are all valid object IDs, but then...)

```
git rev-list --objects --all | tail -10 | head -3 | vis -l
997343e133b42a08059584766e2737632c9c044e read-tree.c\$
2b5bfdf7798569e0b59b16eb9602d5fa572d6038 \$
74a0a234dd346fff51c773aa57d82fc4b83a8557 cat-file.c\$
```

Aha, these do *not* look like valid object IDs, or rather, they are but there is more than just an ID present.  This output is not well documented (I discovered it by testing), but it is *hinted*-at in the `git rev-list` man page:

> Note that [if `--use-bitmap-index` is actually using the bitmap,] when traversing with `--objects`, trees and blobs will not have their associated path printed.

Nonetheless, if we run `git cat-file --batch-check` (without any formats) on these:

```
$ (git rev-list --objects --all | head -3;
   git rev-list --objects --all | tail | head -3) |
  git cat-file --batch-check
d1eae6908f5327c4c1a607cab1c449e71a08c7d7 commit 253
f557ce992dfd61ee7e660eeabb638b99e19bd603 commit 245
ea4daf67a352fa86362e19bb02fd0501a74d26fa commit 239
997343e133b42a08059584766e2737632c9c044e read-tree.c missing
2b5bfdf7798569e0b59b16eb9602d5fa572d6038  missing
74a0a234dd346fff51c773aa57d82fc4b83a8557 cat-file.c missing
```

In my case (git 2.2.0 not 2.3.0), using `wc -l` produces the same number as the number of output lines from `git rev-list --all`, since it counts these error lines.  So I can't explain your particular output—but going back to using `%(rest)`, and the `git cat-file` documentation:

> If this atom [`rest`] is used in the output string, input lines are split at
>              the first whitespace boundary. All characters before that
>              whitespace are considered to be the object name; characters after
>              that first run of whitespace (i.e., the "rest" of the line) are
>              output in place of the `%(rest)` atom.

So:

```
$ (git rev-list --objects --all | head -3;
   git rev-list --objects --all | tail | head -3) |
  git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(rest)'
commit 
commit 
commit 
blob read-tree.c
tree 
blob cat-file.c
```

If you have a `grep blob` or similar in your pipeline, *then* I can explain your results: all the actual blobs result in `<sha1> <filename> missing` and hence get discarded.  [**Edit**: I see by your question-edit that you do in fact have such a grep.  Note that a blob named "blob" will double-match, but that's probably OK. :-)  **Edit 2**: On second thought, beware of a tree with the word "blob" embedded in it, which will get counted: use something like `grep '^blob'` to be safe.]

(Incidentally, `--batch` and `--batch-check` do allow the full range of [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax, but a 40-character SHA-1 followed by a space is invalid, regardless of whatever happens after the space.)

Comment: (Facepalm) Yes, I did have `grep blob`. I will correct my question.